# attribute node and element.attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking at the source to jQuery, specifically `$.fn.prop`.

The following line checks:

```
// don't get/set properties on text, comment and attribute nodes
if ( !elem || nType === 3 || nType === 8 || nType === 2 ) {
    return;
}
```

Which lead to me investigating what an attribute node is. So MDN leads me to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes.

Looking at that, it tells me that `element.attributes` returns attributes for a specific element.

If I reference a video element, and use `element.attributes`, the two attributes are `src` and `style`.

As I am attempting to update the video's `src` value, can I not use `$.fn.prop` to do that because of these two?

What is odd, is `video.nodeType` returns `1` which MDN tells me is an `element` node: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType.

Which has lead to even more confusion.

What is an `attribute` node, and how does that differ to `elements.attributes`?

Answer (score 1):

> What is an attribute node, and how does that differ to elements.attributes?

An attribute node is a data structure representing an attribute  (such as `src`) (including its name and value).

An element node may have zero or more attribute nodes attached to it.

`elements.attributes` is a Node List (which is an Array-like data structure) containing attribute nodes.

> As I am attempting to update the video's src value, can I not use $.fn.prop to do that because of these two?

No. That would stop you trying to change the src attribute of a src attribute (which makes no sense). You are trying to change the src attribute of a video element, which is fine.